# Как получить css свойства с помощью React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть код

```
   linkList=linkStyles.map((linkstyle)=>
     <div>
        <Link linkstyle={linkstyle}/>
        <div> color: {$('.'+{linkstyle}).css('color')}</div>
        <div> text-decoration: {$('.'+linkstyle).css('text-decoration')}</div>
     </div>);
```

linkStyles это массив названий css классов, я хочу вывести свойства каждого класса из этого массива, но не знаю, как именно мне поместить переменную внутрь выражения. Код выше не работает. Можно ли вообще это сделать? Если да то как?

Спасибо!

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму работает, большое спасибо! оформляйте как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код достаточно грязный, выложен с целью показать принцип. Можно сделать чище, и используя всякий сахар вроде компонентов-чистых функций.
Мне было лень разбираться с тем что для этого надо подключать в jsfiddle, поэтому я использовал React.createClass.

Собственно вопроса тут по сути два:
- Где взять стили?
- Как на реакте надо получать DOM ноду?

**jQuery - не нужен.**
Решать это с помощью jQuery - не стоит, потому что jQuery работает с реально существующим домом, никто не гарантирует что реакт его как-то хитро не поменяет, а jQuery про это не узнает ничего.

**Где взять стили?**
Это обычное DOM API, без вмешательства реакта. Пути я вижу два: отрисовать элемент с соответствующим и взять у него стили которые посчитались или лезть в document.styleSheets, выдернуть оттуда нужный фрагмент со стилями и взять из него. Я использовал первый путь, потому что мне так было проще,и для задачи автора этого вроде достаточно.

То есть, `window.getComputedStyle(DOM нода).getPropertyValue(имя свойства)`

В этом подходе есть **нюанс:** нужно отрисовывать список со свойствами после того, как у нас элемент из которого свойства берутся - существует. Для этого у компонента StyleExample есть состояние propertiesSource, которое изменяется после первой итерации отрисовки компонента с помощью [**componentDidMount**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), и условие в методе рендер, которое не отрисовывает список свойств, пока его еще нет.

**Как работать с DOM в реакте?**
В тех случаях когда это нужно (а это реально реже, чем кажется), [**используются refs.**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```js
const StylesContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Здесь список классов:
        {
            this.props.classes.map(cls => <StyleExample clsName = {cls} key = {cls}/>)
        }
    </div>;
  }
});

const StyleExample = React.createClass({
    styleProperties: [
        'color',
        'text-decoration'
    ],
    
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {propertiesSource: null};
    },
    
    componentDidMount: function(){
       this.setState({propertiesSource: this.getPropertiesSource()})
    },
    
    getPropertiesSource(){
       let ref = this.refs[this.props.clsName],
           node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref);
       return window.getComputedStyle(node);
    },
    
    render: function(){
        return <div>
            <LinkMock ref = {this.props.clsName} clsName = {this.props.clsName} />
            {this.state.propertiesSource ?
            <StylePropertiesList styleProperties = {this.styleProperties} 
                                 propertiesSource = {this.state.propertiesSource}
            /> : null}
        </div>
    }
});

const LinkMock = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div className = {this.props.clsName}>Я типа линк {this.props.clsName}</div>
    }
});

const StylePropertiesList = React.createClass({
    getPropertyValue: function(propertyName){
        return this.props.propertiesSource.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
    },

    render: function(){
        return <div>
            {
                this.props.styleProperties.map(propertyName =>
                    <div>{propertyName}: {this.getPropertyValue(propertyName)}</div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <StylesContainer
      classes={["awesomeCls", "greatCls"]}
  />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.awesomeCls{
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.greatCls{
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: overline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {$('.'+{linkstyle}).css('color')}
> ```

```
{$('.'+linkstyle).css('color')}
```

Но вообще-то это жесть такое делать.

Comment: значит посоветуйте альтернативу

Comment: @Oloji, для этого недостаточно кода.

Comment: @Oloji, такое делать действительно не стоит, потому что с помощью jquery вы работаете с реальным домом, а реальный дом - может меняться реактом. Так что любое ($) внутри реактовского компонента это знак "Остановись! Подумай!". А так, я не оч уверен что понял чего Вы хотите, сейчас еще потуплю над вопросом

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму , уже вижу, что это не срабатывает. По сути мне нужно по имени класса вывести некоторые его свойства , когда элемента с таким классом еще нет на странице

Comment: @Oloji, некоторые, это какие? Ограниченный список? Среди них могут быть вычисленные браузером вообще без вашей помощи? Записанные в вашем цсс? Записанные в style конфиге для jsx элемента?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму записанные в файле scss

Comment: @Oloji, всякие css-анимации там могут быть?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму нет, цвет текста и его подчеркивание

Comment: @Oloji, тогда первое что приходит в голову назначить элементу которому вешается стиль ref для доступа к нему с помощью реакта а не jquery, и получать все стили с помощью стандартной dom функции window.getComputedStyle(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myElement)). Разумеется это даст результирующий стиль а не тот, что у вас прописан. Подход в принципе тот же, просто при этом не лезем грязными руками jquery в virtual dom. Если подождете, я пообедаю, потом склею сниппет

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, а это вообще сработает, или даст старый результат? Реакт же ещё не смёрджил DOM?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а ну да, логично, мы ж не отрендерили еще, ща подумаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно дать компоненту состояние типа "элемент отрисовался со стилями", и менять его в сomponentDidMount, еще если автору нужны стили конкретно из его файлика, а не отрисованные, все равно придется руками в document.styleSheets лезть. Ну то есть отрисовать кусок, потом взять из него инфу для другого куска - это реально

Comment: @Qwertiy, proof of concept запилил